# Copy contents of external html table to another html table using Javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am trying to extract a table from an external HTML page and copy its contents to another HTML file I am creating. I tried using the jquery function `.load()` but I do not see the table getting copied. Below is the code I have written -

```
<head>

    <title>Summary Page</title>

</head>

<body>
     <h1>Below is the summary</h1>

     <table id="results"></table>  

     <script type="text/javascript" src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.js">
    $(document).ready(function() {
    $( "#results" ).load( "/Otherpage/Report2.html #TestcasesTable" );
    });
     </script>

</body>
```

In the output HTML page, I only see **Below is the summary** and there is no table displayed, the one that was supposed to be extracted from the external HTML file).

Comment: Is the load definitely being performed? Is it possible that it's being blocked for security reasons? Maybe add a callback function after the load to see what data is being returned

Comment: Your syntax is correct. The only thing that I would say is if `#TestcasesTable` **is** a table, you'll end up with invalid HTML, since you'll be inserting a `<table>` within the `<table id="results">` element. That being said, check that the ID is correct, and **open your developer console**. You'll likely see some errors which may help you figure out what is not working. (press F12)

Comment: Try changing `<table id="results">` to a `<div>` instead and see if that works to prevent nesting a table directly in another table

Comment: The external HTML probably contains references to style sheets and scripts and so forth. What are you doing about those?